# Area of a surface over a triangle.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Find the area of the part of the surface $z=x^2+2y$ that lies above the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,2)$.

Not really sure where to start with this question. So far i have my bounds for $x$ from $0-1$ and for $y$ $0-2$. I have my double integral over $D$ set up but after this I don't really know what to do.

I have my $x^2 +2y$ under a square root with them being squared. But when I try to integrate that it becomes a mess and just does not seem like it is right.

Please help!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have made a mess.

$\iint \|dS\|\ dx\ dy$

$dS = (-\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac {\partial z}{\partial y},1) = (-x,-2, 1)\\
\|dS\| = \sqrt {x^2 + 2}$

your region is bound by the lines, $y = 0, y = 2x,x = 1$

$\int_0^1\int_0^{2x} \sqrt {x^2 + 2}\ dy\ dx$

Comment: That looks so much cleaner then what i was working with. Thank you so much.

Comment: But when i integrate y i get an arcsin. with my integration i am getting x*Sqrt(4x^2+2)+arcsin(sqrt(2))x

Comment: no. after integrating by $y$ you get $y\sqrt{x^2 + 2}|_0^{2x} = 2x\sqrt{x^2+2}$

Comment: okay I understand, Im not quite sure why i had arcsin in my notes when integrating a square root function like that but i see my mistake thank you very much once again.

Comment: if you switched the order of integration, you would get an arcsin function.